# How to create a VM in vCenter from remote source?

Tags: virtual-machine, installation, vmware, automation

For a KVM machine, you can use remote source for installation using virt-install.

Is same possible for a VM in VMWare vCenter?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to automate, you can use PowerCLI. 
https://communities.vmware.com/thread/571516
Another option is to simply create new VM via GUI and then attach ISO to the VM to install OS. 
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1002